# Apt-Offline Unable to Install DKMS?

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, kubuntu, 18.04

I'm trying to resolve a bug with a realtek USB Wi-Fi antenna which requires that I have `dkms` installed. Unfortunately, this is a desktop with no internal Wi-Fi card, and is out of reach of ethernet cables. A bug in the driver tree prevents it from working out of the box.

To install dkms, I used apt-offline and followed the usual scheme of `set` to generate the `.sig` file on the offline computer, and `get` on the online computer, followed by `install` on the offline computer. The snag is that the `.sig` file won't generate due to an error which is unable to locate `dkms`.

[image: Files]

How can I install dkms and all of its dependencies?